# Datetime picker provides an error when the component closed

Tags: angular, kendo-datetimepicker, angular-controlvalueaccessor

I am using Kendo-datetimepicker in my Angular app. In my Reactive form i set the intial value as null for FormControlName. When i close the component without updating any value. It shows the following error. Please someone guide me through this. Thanks in Advance.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isEmpty')
    at DateTimePickerComponent.isEmpty (index.js:8605:53)
    at FloatingLabelComponent.updateState (index.js:463:44)
    at Object.updateState [as next] (index.js:535:40)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183:1)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:1)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:1)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
    at EventEmitter_.next (Subject.js:39:1)
    at EventEmitter_.emit (core.mjs:22416:15)
    at FormControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.mjs:2514:31)
```

Comment: also curios here.